# Paginação sem refresh não receber valor

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tenho três arquivos:

1) `listarusuarios.php` Faz busca no banco de dados para listar

2) `paginação.` que faz a paginação do arquivo

3) `dash.js` aonde mando listar os arquivo sem atualizar a pagina

1) `listarusuario.php` envia o link para o paginação e alguns valores

```
 $paginacao = new \App\adms\Models\helper\AdmsPaginacao(URLADM . 'usuarios/listar' , **'usuarios'**);
```

2) `paginação.php` recebe o link e o segundo valor usuários

```
function __construct($Link, **$Var = null**){
    $this->Link = $Link;
    $this->Var = $Var;
}

$this->Resultado .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="listar('.$iPag.', **'.$this->Var.'**)">'.$iPag.'</a></li>';
```

nessa linha acima que envia os valores para o arquivo js

3) `dash.php` recebe o valores

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var varcomp = "";
   var pagina = 1; //página inicial
   listar(pagina, varcomp); 
}); 

function listar(pagina, varcomp) { 
    var dados = {
    pagina: pagina
    varcomp: varcomp //quando coloca o varcomp a paginçao não funciona
};


   $.post('../../adm/**usuários**/listar/' + pagina + '?tiporesult=1', function (retorna) { // eu quero que seja dinâmico para na parte aonde esta o usuários, entre outros valores ex: paginas
      $("#conteudo").html(retorna);

   });
}
```

já fiz `console.log(varcomp)` aparace o usuários porém da como   **>> 'usuarios' is not defined <<**

Comment: Kayo, dá pra fazer o que você com as tecnologias escolhidas sim, provavelmente alguém vai te responder ai com as dicas, mas porquê não utilizar um framework simples de two-way databinding tipo AngularJS ou VueJS? Outra coisa, sugiro implementar padrões de API que no caso da paginação seria .get e não .post. Quanto mais canônico for seu projeto, melhor para manutenção e para as pessoas ajudarem.

Comment: Falta uma vírgula entre `pagina: pagina` e `varcomp: varcomp`.

Comment: no caso ai eu já coloquei a virgula, qdo digitei aqui eu esqui, mas mesmo assim não da certo

Comment: consegui fazer ficar dinâmico;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui deixar dinâmico, não sei se foi o jeito certo porem esta funcionando muito bem

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var pagina = 1; //página inicial          
  listar(pagina);
});

function listar(pagina) {
    var link = window.location.pathname;
    link = link.replace("/projeto1/", "");
    var niv = link.split("&")[1];
    link = link.split("&")[0];

    var dados = {
        pagina: pagina
    };

$.post('../../' + link + '/' + pagina + '&' + niv + '&tiporesult=1', dados, function (retorna) {
    $("#conteudo").html(retorna);
});
```

}